# Delete created meteor package from atmospherejs

Tags: meteor

I created a package for atmospherejs.com.
Everything worked as expected but now I want to delete it.
How can I remove it from atmosphere?

I found the following explanation but I guess its not up to date:
https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere/issues/53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent packages from showing up in `meteor search` with `meteor admin set-unmigrated`. Checkout their blogpost on [here](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/09/25/meteor-093-packaging-system-updates).

> A new administrative command hides packages from the results of meteor search and meteor show. This is designed to remove mrt-era packages that didn't correctly auto-migrate into the new package system and for cases where authors have changed the name of a package and don't want new developers using the old name. To hide a package, run meteor admin set-unmigrated. Please note that hiding a package does not prevent users from explicitly adding it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do so on the new packageserver as mentioned by tmeasday at the end of the issue.

https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere/issues/53#issuecomment-54010716